# Scale and overlay in single command

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert and resize a video and put a logo on it. I am doing this with 2 different command line like this.

Command 1:

```
D:\Logo\ffmpeg -i "D:\Logo\video.mxf" -vf scale=1280:720 "D:\Logo\video.mxf_fullHDtoHD.mp4"
```

Command 2:

```
D:\Logo\ffmpeg -i "D:\Logo\video.mxf_fullHDtoHD.mp4" -i D:\Logo\logo_720p.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=60:50"  "D:\Logo\output_720p_with_logo.mp4"
```

Can I do this in just one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Logo\video.mxf" -i D:\Logo\logo_720p.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=60:50" "D:\Logo\output_720p_with_logo.mp4"
```